# phpMyAdmin connection timeout. No Login cooke validity option under Settings

Tags: macos, google-chrome, phpmyadmin

This is my first Stack Overflow post ever. Hurah for me :)

phpMyAdmin 4.9.1. How can I change connection timeout? For now it's 1440 seconds.

Settings/Fuatuers/General dosen't show option "Login cookie validity".

OS: MacOS Catalina 10.15.1 (19B88)
Google Chrome Version 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

in phpmyadmin\libraries\config.default.php change

```
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 1440
```

to

```
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 7200;
```

to make session logout after 2 Hours.

Answer (score 1):

in phpmyadmin\libraries\config.default.php change

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 1440
```

to

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

and restart - this will clear the limit

Comment: Still the same. I change what you said but after some time, I am disconnected again. ibb.co/9gsLqFy

Answer (score 0):

try to add the line $cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = '7200' ; into config.inc.php file in PhpMyAdmin directory
this is for two hours

Answer (score 0):

### If you're using phpMyAdmin in a DOCKER container:

1. Go to your `TERMINAL` and list your docker containers in order to find out  the `phpmyadmin` one:

```
$ docker ps

# EXAMPLE OF OUTPUT: 

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                                      NAMES
93dfa1f49775   php:7.4.1-fpm           "docker-php-entrypoi…"   2 weeks ago   Up 2 weeks   9000/tcp                                   docker_localhost_app
36299ca6ce83   nginx:alpine            "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 weeks ago   Up 2 weeks   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   docker_localhost_nginx
c1d8e6ffd28c   phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 weeks ago   Up 2 weeks   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                       docker_localhost_myadmin
d75778f88cc6   mysql:5.6               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 weeks ago   Up 2 weeks   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp                     docker_localhost_db
```

---

2. Execute `bash` in the chosen container:

```
$ docker exec -it docker_localhost_myadmin bash

root@c1d8e6ffd28c:/var/www/html#
```

> In this case `docker_localhost_myadmin` is the name of `my` container.

---

3. Install `vim editor` in order to change the file that have the timeout variable. Execute that:

```
$ apt update
$ apt upgrade
$ apt install vim
```

---

4. Edit the file `config.default.php`:

```
$ vim /var/www/html/libraries/config.default.php
```

---

5. Find out and change the variable `$cfg['LoginCookieValidity']` from `1440` to `28800`(8 hours):

*To find out the variable on `vim`, press `/` and type `LoginCookieValidity`*

**Before:**

```
  $cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 1440
```

**After:**

```
  $cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 28800;
```

> NOTE 1: `DO NOT` set `0`(zero) as it will make your phpMyAdmin logout immediately.

> NOTE 2: You may face a message on your phpMyAdmin like:
>
> *Your PHP parameter session.gc_maxlifetime is lower than cookie validity configured in phpMyAdmin, because of this, your login might expire sooner than configured in phpMyAdmin.*
>
> In this case, change the environment variable `session.gc_maxlifetime` on your docker-compose.yml to `- session.gc_maxlifetime=28800` or bigger.

---

6. Restart your container:

```
$ /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

---

7. Logout and Login your phpMyAdmin to see the results.